# Set VBA Variable to Result from Function which is String

Tags: excel, vba, function

I've read a bunch about functions today and they all seem to deal with math/numbers. I'm trying to use a function which returns a string and capture that as a variable in the "main sub" but I can't get it to work. Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Eg:

**Function:**

```
Public Function Test(var) As Variant
 Bar = var & "World"
 MsgBox Bar
End Function
```

**Sub:**

```
Public Bar As Variant
Public Z As Variant
Sub testing()
 Call Test("Hello") ' This displays "HelloWorld" from MsgBox in Function 
 Test ("Hello")     ' This displays "HelloWorld" from MsgBox in Function 
 Z = Test("Hello")  ' This displays "HelloWorld" from MsgBox in Function 
 MsgBox Z           ' This displays an empty MsgBox :*(
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the function to return a value, populate the function variable and return that in the main sub, like so

```
Public Function Test(var As String) As String
    Test = var & " World"
End Function

Sub testing()
    returnstr  = Test("Hello")
    MsgBox returnstr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't returning a value from the function. Also, functions should only be used to return values, not to perform actions that change things (other than variables) or display pop-ups. It also gets confusing having global variables and passing variables to a function. You generally pass local variables to a function. Here's a cleaner example (with your main function first, as is normal convention):

```
Sub Testing()
    Dim Z As String
    Z = Test("Hello")
    MsgBox Z
    MsgBox Test("Hello")
End Sub

Public Function Test(ByRef var As String) As String
    Test = var & "World"
End Function
```

Comment: I used the MsgBox for debug only, but I'm beginning to see my logic error thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer has answered your question sufficiently, please mark it as correct using the tick to the left. Otherwise you can leave a comment if you want more detail.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers if you accept an answers other users know no additional help is needed :)

Comment: @TimStack, I accept an answer on 99% of my questions just not at work till tomorrow to test and verify. I'm leaning towards Error because he used a global variable but you code was also easy to read and helped me understand my issue. Thank you all rarely do I have such a hard time deciding between good answers!

Comment: Error used a function to modify a global variable, still without returning a value from the function. That's not how functions are supposed to be used. Functions are for returning values. If you only want to modify a global variable, then just use a Sub.

Comment: "_Functions are for returning values_". But what about using Functions for repeated actions? I don't think that holds up

Comment: You use Subs for repeated actions. You call them repeatedly or recursively. The fact that a Function returns a value is the only difference from a Sub. It is its defining purpose. Google "Sub vs Function".

Comment: Functions absolutely can modify variables, both variables passed by reference and global variables, but if it isn't returning a value, then you just use a Sub.